# Structure and memcpy warning

Tags: c, structure, microcontroller, lpc, flash-memory

I would like copy data from flas into RAM (microcontroller) in structure. And I have structure initialization:

```
typedef struct Day{
    long AM : 24;
    long PM : 24;
}Day;

struct Data{
    unsigned long Lang   : 8;
    struct Day dawt[7];

}Data;
```

Load from flash into RAM I have with this function

```
void LoadFromFlash(){
    int count;

    memcpy(Data.Lang, F_DATA, 1);
    for(count = 0; count < 7;  count++){

        memcpy(Data.dawt[count].AM, F_DATA, 3);
        memcpy(Data.dawt[count].PM, F_DATA, 3);
    }
}
```

I get warning:

```
passing argument 1 of 'memcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

for all mempcy function

and

```
passing argument 2 of 'memcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

for #define statement

```
#define F_DATA      0x00006000
```

What's wrong.

Comment: You should immediately go and *fully understand* what the address-of operator  (`&`) does.

Comment: Why are you copying Lang and dawt separately?  Can you copy the entire Data structure at once?  And why is F_DATA the source for all of your calls to memcpy? How is that going to work?

Answer (score 1):

As we can see from the [`memcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) syntax,

```
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
```

the first and second arguments should be of type `void *`.

Now, assuming `Lang` is a member variable of structure variable `Data`, and you have a definition like

```
 Data Data;
```

`Data.Lang` **is** the `long` type member variable, not it's address. You need to use `&Data.Lang`, at least.

That said, in case of a *literal*, like `0x00006000` does not denote an address, you need to cast it like `(void *)0x00006000` to make it interpret like an address.

Comment: @alk yeah, same. Updated.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes I tried added & before, but I get this: cannot take addres of bit-field 'Lang' –

Comment: @SouravGhosh As I can see on other forum all against the use of bit field, but in my case I must use bitfield. Because I say how long is import data. And then I now wher to save in structure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused by the code in your question so I may misunderstand.  But if `Data` is the RAM copy of the struct, and there is a flash copy of the same struct located at the address represented by `F_DATA`, then you should be able to do something as simple as this:

```
void LoadFromFlash(){
    Data = *((struct Data *)F_DATA);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other have pointed out, the memcpy function is interested of the address (e.g. &variable). However, as you have noted in a comment you receive the following error message:

```
cannot take addres of bit-field 'Lang'
```

The reason is:

> Because bit fields do not necessarily begin at the beginning of a byte, address of a bit field cannot be taken. Pointers and non-const references to bit fields are not possible.
>   Bit fields do not have addresses—you can't have pointers to them or arrays of them.

However, I'll try to see if there is a workaround. But for now this should be good enough.

Edit:
Are you the one storing the data in flash?

However, create an union. Within the union create a struct. Copy 3 bytes from the flash into 't'Day.AM. Then read the value from 't'Day.bitfieldAM.AM

```
typedef union
    {
    struct
    {
        long AM:24;
        long: 8;
    }bitFieldAM;
    long AM;

    struct
    {
        long PM:24;
        long: 8;
    }bitFieldPM;
    long PM;

}tDay;
```

Comment: I have to copy the data from RAM to flash, because it is the only way for changing it bit by bit. I can't save bit by bit in RAM, because I don't haveEEPROM in LPC1114. So i got the idea to just copy the datato flash and saving them in the structure, changing it later and writing the structure in RAM.

Comment: Okey, u are using some location in flash as eeprom. Is there a reason why u want the bitfields to be exactly 24bits (3 bytes)? Why not just use the whole 32 bits (4 bytes)? HH:MM:SS, and you allocate 1 byte for each?

Comment: No, I work on thermostat and user must have options for Moon or Sun (ON or Off heater). And I working now on Timer set, where user set for day of week on half hour. So, betwen 00:00 and 4:30 I must have Moon after Sun.  A day have 24 hour, for my options is 48 choose (Moon or Sun, 1 or 0) on day. And 48 x 7 is 336 bits. Or 42 byte. 
In LPC who has not a EEPROM and must stored data into a RAM just at once not bit by bit, I must emulation of EEPROM. And I my data has two field first field is Language (1B). Second field has Timer: Moon and Sun options, who has 336 bits.